# Having trouble grouping data in R using dplyr

Tags: r

I ran this to get number of distinct members by age group in the res1 dataset. However, the count is not grouped and count you see below is for the entire dataset. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Can someone please help me with this? Thank you!

```
res1 %>% group_by(Age_Group = res1[,'age_group']) %>%
      summarise(Count = n_distinct(res1[,'ID']))
Source: local data frame [10 x 2]

#   Age_Group             Count
#      <fctr>             <int>
#1      >= 90            5000
#2        0-9            5000
#3      10-19            5000
#4      20-29            5000
#5      30-39            5000
#6      40-49            5000
#7      50-59            5000
#8      60-69            5000
#9      70-79            5000
#10     80-89            5000
```

Comment: Use `res1 %>% group_by(age_group) %>%  summarise(Count = n_distinct(ID))`. Don't refer to the original data frame in subsequent dplyr steps. That breaks the chain. Use unquoted column names.

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

When you're using the piping operator `%>%` it feeds what's on the left of the operator as the first input to the function on the right of the operator. When you pipe from the `group_by` statement into the summarize statement, there is a hidden unnamed grouped dataframe. But when you define `Count` as `n_distinct(res1[,'ID'])`, you're calling back to the original ungrouped data.frame `res1`, and not the grouped data.frame you created in the `group_by` call. That's why it's giving you the total count, not the count per group.

In a dplyr pipeline like this you should just call the unquoted column names, so this:

```
res1 %>% group_by(Age_Group = age_group) %>%
summarise(Count = n_distinct(ID))
```

should work

Comment: Thanks a lot! That makes sense.

Comment: If an answer answered your question and solved your problem, you can indicate this by accepting the answer (The checkmark beneath the up and down arrows).